# Cordova camera preview cannot show image

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using [Cordova-camera-preview](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview) with ionic framework to make a camera background with interaction with html elements on android platform.

However, I fail to display the image took by this plugin. Here is my code:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.Capture = function(){
        cordova.plugins.camerapreview.takePicture({maxWidth:640, maxHeight:640});
    }

    $scope.StartCamera = function(){
        var rect = {x: 0, y: 0, width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight / 2};
        cordova.plugins.camerapreview.startCamera(rect, "back", false, false, false);

        console.log('camerapreview startCamera');

        window.addEventListener("click", function(){
            cordova.plugins.camerapreview.focus();
        });

        cordova.plugins.camerapreview.setOnPictureTakenHandler(function(src){
            console.log(src[1]);
            // Here I obtain: /data/data/com.ionicframework.ionicproject711981/files/camerapreview_09_11_2016_1039_34_preview.jpg

            document.getElementById('preview').src = src[1];
            // I put the src into the image and I get a '?' which denote 404 error.
        });
    }


    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){

        console.log('deviceready');
        $scope.StartCamera();

    }, false);

})
```

Can someone helpS?

Comment: I solve the problem by modifying the path ``src`` like ``cdvfile://localhost/cache/xxxx.jpg``